# How to insert contact from a new inserted Customer in Microsoft dynamics nav

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I have a XML file with customers and contacts.

I can a new customer. But by that customer belongs several contacts. And I want to insert all the contact belong to that Customer.

But now I will get all the contacts and not only the contacts belong to that new inserted Customer.

This is the code:

```
MESSAGE("<Customer>"."No.");
IF "<Customer>"."No." = '783100' THEN
BEGIN
  IF "<Contact>".FINDSET  THEN
  REPEAT
//DisplayCustomerData;
  MESSAGE("<Contact>".Name);
  UNTIL "<Contact>".NEXT  = 0;
     END;
```

Answer (score 0):

in Dynamics NAV, Customers and Contacts are linked. This means if you create a new Customer the system will create a new Contact in the background and link them together (Contact Business Relation). 
If you want to create only a Contact (what is the difference? Customers have financial details, posting setups etc. Contact's doesn't) create a new Contact. If you want to create new Customer create a one and the system will create a new Contact in the background.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I Hope you want to import a customer and all its contacts.

To do this create a XML port.

http://s32.postimg.org/tjtak28lh/Capture.png
This is a screenshot, how the XMLPort structure should look like. Add all fields you want.

To import the XML via this XMLPort, you needs to re structure the XML file as the XMLPort is. LIKE-

```
<Root>
 <Header>
 <Customer>
  <FiledName/>
  <FieldName/>
   <Contact>
    <FieldName/>
    <FieldName/>
   </Contact>
    <Contact>
    <FieldName/>
    <FieldName/>
   </Contact>
 </Customer>
</Header>
</Root>
```

In C/AL code editor write code in OnPostXMLPort() if you need.